# How to get access to the own methods of anonymous inner class

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

Can anybody help to optimize the mess in my head produces the following stupid code snippet?

```
public class SomeClass {

    interface MethodInvokeHelper{
        void methA(int funNum, Object ... v);
        <T> T methB(int funNum, Object ... v);
    }

    static class SomeInnerClass{
        void someMethod(){System.out.println("SomeInnerClass method");}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodInvokeHelper anonymous = new SomeInnerClass(){

            void methAnonym1(){ System.out.println("methAnonym1"); }

            void methAnonym2(){ System.out.println("methAnonym2"); }

            Integer methAnonym3(){ return 10;}

            String methAnonym4(){return "methAnonym4";}

            Integer methAnonym5(Object ... v){
                    int sum = 0;
                    for (Object i : v)
                            if(i instanceof Integer)sum += (int) i;
                            else return 0;
                    return sum;
            }

            MethodInvokeHelper refs(){

                    return new MethodInvokeHelper(){
                        public void methA(int funNum, Object ... v) {
                            switch(funNum){
                                case 1 -> methAnonym1();
                                case 2 -> methAnonym2();
                            }
                        }
                        public Object methB(int funNum, Object ... v) {
                                return switch(funNum){
                                        case 1 -> methAnonym3();
                                        case 2 -> methAnonym4();
                                        case 3 -> {
                                                if(v.length>0) yield methAnonym5(v);
                                                else yield null;
                                        }
                                        default -> null;
                                };
                        }
                    };}
            }.refs();

        anonymous.methA(1);
        System.out.println((Object) anonymous.methB(1));
        System.out.println((Object) anonymous.methB(3,3,4));
    }
```

I just want to bypass the constraints of use the own methods of anonymous inner class inside outer code.

**Update:** by @Old Dog Programmer comment the names of classes have been changed.

**Update to clarify by propose of @Sweeper:** So let specify the problem that inducted the question above:

In the following code:

```
public class Outer {
        Outer(){}
        void method() {
                System.out.println("the method of Outer");
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Outer outter = new Outer() {
                        { super.method(); method(); nmethod(); }
                        void method(){
                                System.out.println("method() from anonymous class");
                        }
                        void nmethod() {
                                System.out.println("nmethod() from anonymous class");
                        }
                };
                outter.method(); // we can call the overriden method
                // outter.nmethod(); //but we can not call the own method of anonymous inner class from outside
        }
    }
```

So, I want to find a possibility to call `outter.nmethod();`

Comment: Can you show what code you *wanted* to write, but couldn't? What was the original invalid code that you try to fix with this mess?

Comment: @Sweeper, there is no any original codes. The main target is to get access to the own methods of anonymous inner class. But this code I molded on in the free manner, for my oppinion, is looking bad.

Comment: Get access to which methods? Access from where? The code is too messy that I can't really see what you mean. Also, why are you doing this in the first place? Could this be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @Sweeper, OK. This question in another words may by sound so that can anybody propose the way to bypass the constraints of use the own methods of anonymous inner class such that we will posible to call their by use of object variable in the same manner as the overriden versions of the base class methods?

Comment: You mentioned a "constraint", but I don't know what "constraint" you mean. Can you demonstrate what constraint you are trying to bypass by showing some code that doesn't compile (because of the constraint)?

Comment: Are you trying to get access to `methAnonym1`, `methAnonym2` etc? Why use an anonymous class then? How about just writing a *named* class? It can still be local to the `main` method.

Comment: @Sweeper, We can do almost anything. But what about to force the impossible.

Comment: Well if you are just trying to make a point and not intend to use the language properly, you already did it. There is no problem with using this code, if you are just trying to make a point. I would be surprised if this could be done in a non-messy way, because the language is not designed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do understand the question correctly, it can be done using `var` (Java 10 or later) to declare the variable like in:

```java
var outter = new Outer() {  // or just new Object()
    void nmethod() {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
    void omethod() {
        System.out.println("Another method");
    }
};

outter.nmethod();
outter.omethod();
```

It is like the compiler knowns the type of the anonymous class.

Comment: It is the same if we will use the "anonymous object" for this anonymous inner class, i.e. 
new Outer() {
    void nmethod() {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
}.nmethod();
This is "one-time promotion" for use just one of the own non-overriden methods to call. And it is naturally because of the absence as of the actual object type as of the absence the object variable as well and as the result, we have access to the own members of anonym, but due to naming absense this access applies to a single method.

Comment: it is similar, but not the same since it can be used multiple times, and for more than one method or field. You asked "*I want to find a possibility to call `outter.nmethod();`*"... now you have two alternatives